# Inequivalent definitions of the support of a Borel measure

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, definition, borel-measures

*All definitions appearing in this question apply to Borel measures.*

Many sources (including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory)#Definition) and [Folland](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Real+Analysis%3A+Modern+Techniques+and+Their+Applications%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471317166)) define the support of a Borel measure to be the set of points whose open neighborhoods all have positive measure, or equivalently

- the intersection of the closed sets of full measure, or
- the complement of the union of the open null sets.

Some other sources (including [Bogachev](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-62)) declare a set to be the support if and only if it is a minimal closed set of full measure. This definition implicitly acknowledges that such a set may not exist.

Finally, there are some (including [Kallenberg](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953137)) that declare the support to be the smallest closed set of full measure. Is this notion well-defined? If not, what is a (preferably explicit and self-contained with all details worked out) example of a Borel measure for which there does not exist a smallest closed set of full measure?

**Edit:** According to the responses to this question, the third definition is ill-defined in the absence of regularity assumptions. This seems to be a (relatively minor) mistake in Kallenberg's book (and in other places where this definition is used) or at least a case of implicit assumptions.

Comment: Normally we’d work with measures that have regularity properties, not just Borel. That might give a better chance at a good definition.

Comment: Defining support in any of those ways does not make sense unless there is some relationship between measure and topology.

Comment: @tomasz all three definitions apply only to Borel measures, as mentioned at the start of my question, although I have just now added the italicized text at the start making this more explicit. Does this address your concern?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma this is a fair point, although (if you have access to e.g. Kallenberg's book) will you concede that some authors use the problematic third definition without making any regularity assumptions? (It really is clear-cut in Kallenberg's case, as measure is defined on page 7 in the first edition and on page 9 the support is defined for any Borel measure on an arbitrary topological space using the problematic definition before any regularity hypothesis has even been introduced in the book itself.)

Comment: Borelness alone is not quite sufficent. However, a *finite* Borel measure on a well-behaved topological space (e.g. Polish) is automatically regular, in which case all of these make much more sense.

Comment: @tomasz not quite sufficient for what? It is certainly sufficient to make the first two definitions above well-defined, although it is not sufficient to ensure that the support has full measure.

Comment: @pre-kidney: Not sufficient for the definition to really make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal (or smallest) closed set of full measure need not always be well-defined.
The "example" (which we cannot show to exist in ZFC) is a discrete space $X$ with a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ (look up [real-valued measurable cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal#Real-valued_measurable)) that is $0$ on all singletons: for every closed set $C$ with $\mu(C)=1$, then if $x \in C$, $\mu(C\setminus\{x\}) =1$ too and this set is closed and strictly smaller. So only the empty set is minimal.

There are no points all of whose neighbourhoods are of positive measure. If course this measure is not tight, as the only compact sets are finite and thus measure $0$. So the intersection of all closed sets of full measure is $\emptyset$ which does not have full measure, and this is indeed the complement of the union all open null sets. So in that sense it's defined, but it's "useless".

————————————————————-

**Added**: Another classical, better, somewhat related example (in ZFC !) is the $0$-$1$-probability measure on $\omega_1$, which is explained [here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~anush/Courses/2018_S.Math574.ST/Other%20files/Lutzer%20D%20--%20Stationary%20sets%20in%20omega_1,%20Ulam%20matrices,%20and%20probability%20measures.pdf), the so-called Dieudonné measure (as Halmos calls it in in Measure Theory):

The set $X$ is just the ordinal number $\omega_1$ in its order topology (Munkres calls this space $W$, others call it $\Omega$) and a measure $\mu$ is defined on its Borel sets by $\mu(A) = 1$ iff there is a closed and unbounded set (a "club") that is a subset of $A$; otherwise $\mu(A) = 0$. As clubs are closed under countable intersections, this does define a somewhat unintuitive Borel measure on $X$, with the properties that $\mu(X) =1$, $\mu(\{x\}) = 0$ for all $x \in X$ (a singleton is not unbounded) and even $\mu(K) = 0$ for all compact subsets of $X$ (as these are bounded above and so don't contain a club). If $C$ is a closed set of measure $1$ (so it's actually a club) it will contain many isolated points $p$ (all successor ordinals are isolated in $X$) and then $C\setminus \{p\}$ is a strictly smaller closed set of full measure. So there cannot be a minimal closed set of full measure. Of course the measure is not inner regular for compact sets, but it is inner regular for closed sets, almost by definition. Ulam already showed that we cannot extend this measure to all subsets of $\omega_1$, but on the Borel sets it's well-defined.

If a probability Borel measure is tight (inner regular for compact sets) then defining $$N = \bigcup \{U| U \text{ open }, \mu(U)=0\}$$ the set $N$ has measure $0$: any compact $K \subseteq N$ is covered by finitely many open null sets, so has measure $0$ too and so $\mu(N) = \sup \{\mu(K): K \subseteq N, K \text{ compact }\} = 0$ and in that case the support

$$X\setminus \bigcup\{U: U \text{ open }, \mu(U)=0\}=
\bigcap \{ C: C \text{ closed }, \mu(C)=1\}$$ has full measure and is indeed minimal with that property in that case.

So the “problem” is solved by considering suitably regular Borel measures. That’s why in analysis applications only Radon or tight measures are considered. See also the Handbook of Set-theoretic Topology (1984), one of my "bibles", in the chapter on Borel measures, for more discussion of such issues.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail some of the claimed properties of Dieudonne measure to make the answer more self-contained? For example, what exactly are the points of the space, what is the topology, why do compacta have a null neighborhood (what even is your precise definition of a compactum), what is the exact meaning of an unbounded set in this space, why does each club of full measure contain a strictly smaller one?

Comment: @pre-kidney I added some details, not full proofs which can be found in the linked notes or any good set-theory book that covers properties of $\omega_1$. It's one of the standard "weird measures" one uses to check hypotheses etc.