# Two equivalent definitions of the support of a measure

Tags: measure-theory

**Disclaimer**

This thread is meant to record. See: [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762).

Anyway, it is written as problem. Have fun! :)

---

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mu$ a non-negative Borel measure on $X$. Fox $x\in X$, let $\mathcal N_x$ be the collection of all open neighborhoods (nbh) of $x$. Let
> $$
> S_1 := \{ x\in X \mid \forall N \in \mathcal N_x: \mu(N)>0\}
> \quad \text{and} \quad
> S_2 := \bigcap \{A \mid A \text{ is closed}, \mu(A^c)=0\}.
> $$
> Then $S_1 =S_2$.

---

*Update:* By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2968686/368425) question, it's worth noticing that $S_2$ does not necessarily have full measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $x \notin S_2$. Then there is a closed set $A$ such that $\mu(A^c)=0$ and $x \notin A$. Clearly, $A^c$ is an open nbh of $x$. Then $x \notin S_1$.

Assume $x \notin S_1$. Then there is $N \in \mathcal N_x$ such that $\mu(N)=0$. Clearly, $N^c$ is closed and its complement has measure $0$. Also, $x \notin N^c$ and thus $x\notin S_2$.

It follows that $S_1 = S_2$.

---

Now let $X$ be a separable metric space and $B \in \mathcal B(X)$ such that $\mu(B)>0$. Then $B \cap S_1 \neq \emptyset$.

---

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and $\mu, \nu$  Borel probability measures on $X,Y$ respectively. Let $\pi$ be a Borel probability measure on $X \times Y$ with marginals $\mu, \nu$ respectively. If $(x,y) \in \operatorname{spt} \pi$, then $x \in \operatorname{spt} \mu$ and $y \in \operatorname{spt} \nu$. If not, assume $x \notin \operatorname{spt} \mu$. Then there is a nbh $N$ of $x$ such that $\mu(N)=0$. Then $\mu(N \times Y) = \mu(N)=0$. On the other hand, $N \times Y$ is a nbh of $(x,y)$, so $(x, y) \notin \operatorname{spt} \pi$ which is a contradiction.