# The concentration of a measure $\mu$ on a single point in case $\mu$ satisfies this special property

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space and $\mu$ a Borel probability measure on $E$. Assume $\mu$ has a property that if $(E_1, E_2)$ is a measurable partition of $E$, i.e., $E_1 \cap E_2 = \emptyset$ and $E_1 \cup E_2 = E$, then either $\mu(E_1)=0$ or $\mu(E_1)=1$. Let $U$ be the support of $\mu$, i.e., $U$ is the intersection of all closed sets with full measure.

If $E$ is **separable**, [then](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44408/measure-of-the-support-of-a-borel-probability-on-a-metric-space) $\mu(U) = 1$ and thus $U \neq \emptyset$. We fix $a \in U$. Then $(B(a, 1/n), (B(a, 1/n))^c)$ is a measurable partition of $E$, with $B(a, 1/n)$ being the open ball centered at $a$ with radius $1/n$. It follows that $\mu(B(a, 1/n)) > 0$ and thus $\mu(B(a, 1/n)) = 1$ for all $n$. Hence $\mu (\{a\})=1$ and thus $U = \{a\}$.

> Do we have the same conclusion, i.e., $\mu$ concentrates on a single point, if we drop the hypothesis that $E$ is separable?

Comment: Where do you think you used separability here ? I ask because I think you didn't.

Comment: @P.Quinton please see the link I attach "...[then](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44408/measure-of-the-support-of-a-borel-probability-on-a-metric-space)...".

Comment: My bad, I thought you defined the support to be the intersection of full measure closed sets.

Comment: In general $\mu (U)=1$ need not hold. There may be no smallest closed set with measure $1$.

Comment: There is  a beautiful result which says that if there is a smallest closed set of measure $1$ then the set is necessarily separable. So $\mu$ sits in a separable set and your argument works fine to show that $\mu$ is degenerate.

Comment: In addition I think the link you provide gives an example of measure where the support is empty.

Comment: Why does it follow that $\mu(B(a,1/n))>0$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It's due to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4443496/1019043) equivalent definition of the support.